# Spyder automatic import of submodules

Tags: python, spyder

This code fails in all the Python environments I have, but not in Spyder:

```
import scipy
print(scipy.integrate.cumtrapz([1, 2, 3]))
```

In most environments you would get

```
AttributeError: module 'scipy' has no attribute 'integrate'
```

unless you did `import scipy.integrate` to get the submodule imported, but somehow, in Spyder this code runs without error if you use the "Execute in current Python or IPython console" run configuration. It fails if you use "Execute in a new dedicated Python console". Clearly Spyder is doing something to import the submodule automatically, but I cannot find this behaviour documented anywhere.

**The questions** are what is Spyder doing, where is this documented and how can I turn it off.

Environment: Anaconda 3 (4.3.0), Spyder 3.1.2, Python 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can switch from the IPython console to the Python console (it's a different tab there). The problem is that IPython in different modes (i.e. "matplotlib" mode) loads a lot of stuff and this stuff loads a lot of stuff. It's basically impossible to control that.

[image]

However there are certainly ways to modify the IPython startup under `Tools -> Preferences -> IPython console`, but I'm not sure if you can disable the `SciPy` import there.

Comment: I  also thought it was automatic imports, but if you leave out the scipy import the code fails. So it's more subtle than that.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon if you try `import sys; print(sorted(sys.modules.keys()))` you get all loaded modules. It's important to know that imported doesn't mean that you can use it in the interpreter (because it was loaded in another scope/namespace), it just means that it was loaded anywhere.

Comment: That's getting closer to an answer then. I'm still interested in why/how the code will fail if I don't `import scipy` but succeed if I do that but I don't `import scipy.integrate`

Comment: Because `scipy.integrate` is already in your `sys.modules` but you need to import `scipy` because you otherwise get a `NameError` with scipy.